# SQL. Вывод записей из таблицы только если поле timestamp не больше N

Tags: sql, join, запрос, group-by, inner-join

Всем привет.

Допустим есть две таблицы: пользователи и логи входа в систему.

Логи входа соответственно содержат `id` пользователя и например `timestamp` входа.

Не могу понять как вывести сгруппированный вывод по id пользователя и количеству записей в логах входа, если например есть несколько записей `timestamp` которых между записями не превышает `N` секунд.

```sql
SELECT a.*, COUNT(a.id) 
  FROM logons AS a
  JOIN logons AS b on a.id != b.id
 WHERE a.id < b.id 
   AND (b.created - a.created) < N
 GROUP BY a.user_id
```

Такой запрос выводит огромное кол-во count, хотя вроде явно указанно что одинаковые id не сравнивать.
Подскажите пожалуйста как быть.

Comment: А вы не пишите в выборке a.*, а укажите только те поля, которые действительно нужны. Потому как она стремится показать все записи отличающиеся хоть одним полем

Answer (score 1):

Хотья тут не указано какое БД вы используете, но могу посоветовать следуюшее

в *Postgres* имеется функция `lag` который дает предыдуший результат в запросе. С помошью этой функции ваш запрос можно сделать с одним таблицой. примерно так

```sql
SELECT id, count(difference)
  FROM (
    SELECT event_id, created - lag(created) OVER (order by id, created) as difference 
      FROM logons AS a
     GROUP BY id) t
 ORDER BY id, created
```

тут

`lag(created)` - это значение `created` предыдущей строки

`created` - это значения текушей строки

`difference`  - это разница времени между предыдущей и текушей строк

или еще проше

```sql
SELECT event_id, SUM(
   CASE WHEN created - lag(created) OVER (order by id, created) <N 
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0) AS cou
 FROM logons AS a
GROUP BY id
```

[документация](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)

---

Функцию `lag` из *postgres* можно в *mysql* сделать таким образом

```
SET @quot=-1;
select time,company,@quot lag_quote, @quot:=quote curr_quote
  from stocks order by company,time;
```

тут

`lag_quote` - это значение предыдущей строки
`curr_quote` - это значения текушей строки

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316349/4953620)

Comment: Вообще проверяю это на MySQL, но хотелось бы не привязываться к БД. Использовать стандарт ANSI.